# React- How to update child prop based on parent state

Tags: reactjs

I'm running into a problem getting a child react component to update when its parent stage changes. I have an Editor parent component that sets its state and then updates the state if the component receives an updated schedule (from a graphQL mutation component).

The problem is that `componentDidUpdate` triggers which does trigger the Modefield to update, but it is **before** the `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` can update the state. This means the child doesn't update. (Note- I know a more idiomatic way is to get rid of state all together, but this way allows a field to both edit and create a new one.)

How can I cause the child to update based on the parent's state change?

```
export const updateScheduleMutation = gql`
  mutation updateScheduleMutation(
    $id: ID!
    $mode: String
  ) {
    updateSchedule(
      id: $id
      mode: $mode
    ) {
      id
      mode
    }
  }
`;

class EditorWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = { scheduleId: props.scheduleId || '' };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Mutation mutation={updateScheduleMutation}>
              {(updateSchedule, { mutationData }) => <Editor {...data} updateSchedule={updateSchedule} />}
            </Mutation>
        )
    }
}

class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { schedule } = props;
    if(schedule === null){
        this.state = {
        schedule: { mode: schedule.mode || "" }
        };
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.schedule !== this.props.schedule) {
      this.setState({ ...this.props.schedule });
    }
  }

  changeInput = (path, input) => {
    const { updateSchedule, schedule } = this.props;
    const field = path.split('.')[1];
    updateSchedule({ variables: { id: schedule.id, [field]: input } });
    this.setState({ [path]: input });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <ModeField input={this.state.schedule.input} />
    );
  }
}

const ModeField = ({input}) => FormControl value={input} />
```

EDIT: I updated the component to show the higher level graphQL wrapper. The reason why I wanted state in the Editor component is that in the event the graphQL query comes back as null, I set this.state.mode to an empty string, which I then update on change. Then, I would create a new schedule item on submit.

Comment: What's `this.stateinput`? Please don't redact the code so it doesn't make sense. Also looks like you're unnecessarily copying `schedule.mode` to state (unless there's some mutation in this component also redacted), wherever possible avoid that.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is designed to respond to state updates from the parent. It's bad practice (in other words, confusing) to use that method to set a new state in this child component. Instead, just calculate what should render in this child component in `componentDidUpdate`, directly based on `this.props.schedule`. There's no need for a `setState` here.

Comment: @nnyby I agree with you. This is a typical example where a presentational, functional component is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LIFT THE STATE UP! Try to manage the base state of your data in parent component and use the data as props in your component:

You also can try getDerivedStateFromProps, but before check the react blog advices:

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm doing right? My parent component manages all of the state and passes it via props into the child components.

Comment: No, you have to use it directly in your component AS PROP that can be just a plain function in this case.  So you will access to the prop like "props.schedule" avoiding to store it in local state

Comment: I updated the code to reflect why I want state- I use the state in the case that the higher level wrapper comes back as null because that state holds that information that I'd submit to create a new schedule. Given the response, perhaps creating an editor component for new with state and another one for editing with props is a better option.

Comment: The point is to mantain a unique source of truth, then propagate it down by props wherever needed. If you need to store a local state as backup maybe the check on null must be done in parent component, before setState, where state resides. Please read from top to bottom my link on react.js blog, it point out bad and best pratice on topic

Comment: Separating my concerns was absolutely the way to go- so much simpler. Thanks for calling me out that I was making an anti-pattern! Cheers! :)

Comment: If the parent component manages state, and it sets the props of the child component based on that state, updating the parent state does not pass in a new set of props to the child component, or does not trigger a re-render of the child component. At least, it does not do this consistently. This is not a solution at all.

Comment: "Lifting up the state" meaning is to manage state in parent component, then pass down needed props. As link to official blog states, cheers mate.